# can I use an elf file as a library for an apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, elf

I have code I compiled already, and wonder if I can use the resulting executable, which is in elf format as a library in an APK and how please.

@Gabe Sechan; thanks. I did build a JNI project. I am having some issues importing the code from my other project into JNI. I wonder if you can suggest the best way to import it. I can post my Android.mk file if you like. Basically, it seems that project finds the first file, and an associated header file. That file, in turn uses variables, which are defined in another file. But there is no include statement.

You know? I figured if I can use a JAR file as a library, perhaps I could use an executable also. I need to learn more.

@ Chris Straton - Thanks. I did edit my post with a comment to address the toolchain issue. But then, I modified it. Regardless, What I stated was if I use the toolchain that is recommended by my target platform, then I should be able to run it on my phone right?

Further; I re-read your comment about ABI and libc compatibility. The two devices are tegra t132 and Samsung S-N900P. So libc should not be an issue since both devices run Android; right? As far as I know both have an arm chip. Is there anything else I need to look into?

Comment: The most critical question will be if your elf file contains code which is compatible with the ABI of your android device, and if it has dependencies - such as to a typical arm-linux glibc - which would not be met on Android's unique bionic-libc based platform.  It is almost always necessary to rebuild programs and libraries using an Android toolchain, unless you are embarking on the large project of adding a more traditional Linux runtime (and associated libraries) to an Android system - for example the "Debian in a chroot" idea.

Comment: Now that you've explicitly stated that your elf is an executable and not a library, that may well add additional complications.  But you are still overlooking the most important issue, which is that either type of elf generally needs to be built with a toolchain compatible with the device on which you wish to use it.

Answer (score -2):

Elf is an executable, not a library.  What you want to do is get a .so file and link to it via JNI.

You could possibly run it as a command line program and interact with it via its stdin and stdout, but that would be clunky when you can just use it as an actual library.

Comment: This is incorrect - shared libraries on Linux are generally, and on Android specifically, stored in elf format.